# Problems with pushing pod files and app extensions to Github

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode8

I have some troubles with Github:

When I am pushing my Xcode project to github, it seems that it won't push all files regarding the pods and app extensions because when I pull the project down on my other mac, I get a whole lot of errors that is not there on the original file.

Thanks in advance!

[image: The errors I get]

Comment: The files are not checked in. Post your `.gitignore` file. In regards of pods, `pod install` will probably fix the error.

Comment: How do I post my .gitignore file? I have tried "pod install" and it did not work... @shallowThought

Comment: @Magnus Please update your title: you seem to understand already that it's _you_ who isn't pushing the files, not Github. Next, follow the steps in my answer to update your question with the contents of the `.gitignore` file, so we can continue solving your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of testing I found the answer. When I used the command lines in terminal for pushing the project to Github, instead of the shortcuts in Xcode, I saw that this files were not "added" to the committing (I checked this by typing: `git status`). Then all I had to do was to write in Terminal: `git add -A` to add all the files. I committed and pushed them to Github, and now everything is working fine!

Thanks for all the help I got!

Answer (score 2):

As shallowThought is suggesting, extend your question with your `.gitignore` file, so we can identify the lines that are likely preventing git from tracking the pods and extensions.

If you are unsure how to find and copy this `.gitignore` file, do the following:

1. In Xcode, on the left open the *Project Navigator* (folder icon) & select your project (usually the top item in the list).
2. From the *File* Menu, choose *Show in Finder*.
3. Finder will open with `<your-project>.xcodeproj` selected. If you don't see the folder that contains `<your-project>.xcodeproj`, press `⌘ 3` to tell Finder to *View as Columns*.
4. De-select `<your-project>.xcodeproj` and instead drag *the folder that contains it* onto the Terminal icon (usually in the bottom of the screen). If Terminal was not there, first start Terminal; e.g. by pressing `⌘ Space` and typing Terminal.
5. Now, Terminal is showing the commandline in the same place where your `.gitignore` file usually is—*technically it can be in any subfolder.*
6. Type `pbcopy < .gitignore` followed by `Enter` to copy the contents of the file in your clipboard.

… now post the contents in your question.

---

Another way to check if indeed git is not tracking your desired files is opening Terminal, and running the following command ([from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/429694)): `git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only`
If Git is not tracking the files that you require, they will not be in the list.

---

If you want to solve this yourself, your best bet is to remove the line from the `.gitignore` file that is preventing *Pods* etc. to be tracked. So, you're are actually doing the opposite of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239746/3419541) ;-)
In step 3. type `open -a "TextEdit" .gitignore` followed by `Enter` to open the file.
Then remove the line(s) that you don't want ignored. Save. Now you can add/commit/push the files to GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your help @PDK! In your second suggestion I get a whole lot of names in terminal, but when I try `open -a "TextEdit" .gitignore` in terminal I get the answer: `.gitignore does not exist.`. Should I create a .gitignore file or is it just hiding somewhere else?

Comment: _"whole lot of names"_, but *not* the Pods and Extension you're looking for? Then they might indeed be ignored. In step 5. we assumed the `.gitignore` would be in that folder; however, it can be in a subfolder. To try to find other `.gitignore` files, type `find . -name .gitignore` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5905066/3419541)

Comment: Hi @PDK. When I did this command I think might have found the `.gitignore` file: `/.cocoapods/repos/master/.gitignore`, but I can´t find a way to open that file...