# Not able to remove .xcworkspace even after running pod clean commands

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to remove pod dependency for committing in to gitlab

I am referring [Remove or uninstall library previously added : cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods) when I do  pod clean  it is showing Unknown command: `clean`

```
pod clean
```

I am expecting to remove pod files while committing and after taking checkout I want to get pod file by running pod install

Comment: You can add pods to your gitignore file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239746/5084797

Comment: pod file is getting removed when I do pod deintegrate, but pod clean is not working

Comment: [cocoapods-clean](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods-clean)'s (`pod clean`) github source appears to have been renamed, you can find it [here](https://github.com/maxerogers/cocoapods-clean) now but all it does is: `rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods *.xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below commands to clear all pod data. Also to ignore pod file while committing to git you can add pod folder path in .gitignore (hidden file) to ignore specific folder on code push.

> pod cache clean --all
> pod deintegrate

OR

> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
>
> rm -rf Pods

Also clear derived data of that app.

Comment: I tried pod cache clean --all but  .xcworkspace still exist

Comment: @mobileapps can you update all the commands you have used to deintegrate pod?? Also I have edited may answer.

Comment: sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
Same order I used

Comment: Ok. Hope this url helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project